# Mathematical Notation for Mixed Effect Model in Bayesian Framework

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, mixed-model, notation

I would like to convert my bayesian mixed effect model into a mathematical notation and am unsure what the correct notation would be here. Can anyone help me or recommend a reference where I could look this up?

```
prior <- c(set_prior("cauchy(0,0.3)", class = "sd"),
          set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "b"),
          set_prior("normal(0,10000)", class = "sigma"))

fit <- brm(Y ~ 0 + factor(A) + B + C + (0 + B| A), 
            data = dat, prior = prior, iter = 4000)
```

This is what my first attempt would look like, however it is not elegant nor am I sure it would be correct that way.

\begin{aligned}
 \operatorname{Y}_{ij}  &\sim N \left(\mu_{i}, \sigma^2\right) \\
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
E(\operatorname{Y{ij}}) = \beta_{0}(A) + \beta_{1j} (A) + \beta_{2j} (B) +
\beta_{3} (C) + \epsilon_{ij}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
E(Y_{ij}) = \beta_0(A) + (\beta_{1}(A) + \upsilon_{1j}(A)) + (\beta_{2}(B) + \upsilon_{2j}(B)) + \beta_{3}(C) + \epsilon_{ij}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
E(Y_{ij}) = \beta_0(A) +  \beta_{1}(A) + \beta_{2}(B) + \beta_{3}(C) + \upsilon_{1j}(A)+ \upsilon_{2j}(B) + \epsilon_{ij}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\upsilon_{1j} \sim N(0, \tau^2_{\upsilon_{1j}}) \\ \upsilon_{2j} \sim N(0, \tau^2_{\upsilon_{2j}})
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
Cov(\sigma^2_{\upsilon_{0j}}, \sigma^2_{\upsilon_{2j}}) = \sigma^2_{\upsilon_{0j}, \upsilon_{2j}}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
\beta_{1j} \\
\beta_{2j}
  \end{array}
\right)
&\sim N \left(
\left(   \begin{array}{c}
\mu_{\beta_{1j}} \\
\mu_{\beta_{2j}}
  \end{array}
\right) , 
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\sigma_{\beta_{1j}} & \rho_{\beta_{1j}\beta_{2j}} \\
\rho_{\beta_{2j}\beta_{1j}} & \sigma_{\beta_{1j}}
  \end{array}\right) 
\right) , for \ A \ j = 1, ...,J
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\sigma_{e}&\sim HalfCauchy(0, 0.3) \\ \sigma_{A} &\sim N(0, 10000) \\ \beta &\sim N(0,10)
\end{aligned}

PS: `equatiomatic` is unfortunately not yet optimized for this kind of formula.

Comment: I would start by running `make_stancode(Y ~ 0 + factor(A) + B + C + (0 + B| A), data = dat, prior = prior)` to see what model brms is actually compiling here. It's not always straightforward to parse, because brms optimises your code in ways that make it faster to run, but harder to read, but it's a good start!

Comment: Dear @Eoin thanks for your advice. I tried it but I have to admit that I am quite confused by the output. Can you recommend a source, that would help me to better understand it?